# BigQuery - Error : Unrecognized name at employees.name, employees.role, Department.name, employees.department_id

Tags: sql, database, join, google-bigquery, inner-join

I was following along with my instructor, and I can't seem to get pass a particular issue. The topic is using the JOIN function particularly the INNER JOIN to aggregate data from two tables in a dataset. I created a dataset(employee_data), in the dataset I also created two tables(employees, Department). This two tables have department_id column. The exercise was to get the list of employees and their department name, excluding any employee without a department_id using the INNER JOIN function. The employees table as the following columns(name, department_id, role), while the Department table as the following columns(name, department_id)

```
SELECT  
employees.name AS employees_name,
employees.role AS employees_role,
Department.name AS department_name

FROM `employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
`employee_data.Department` ON
employees.department_id = department.department_id
```

I keep getting an error of `unrecognized name at employees.name, employees.role, Department.name, employees.department_id`

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, when you are selecting a column in a specific table with a `table_name.column`, your table name must be specified with a dataset name (e.g. `dataset.table`.column).

```
SELECT
 `employee_data.employees`.name AS employees_name,
 `employee_data.employees`.role AS employees_role,
 `employee_data.Department`.name AS department_name
FROM
 `employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
 `employee_data.Department`
ON
 `employee_data.employees`.department_id = 
 `employee_data.Department`.department_id;
```

Instead, give an alias name to the table and select a column using it.

```
SELECT
 e1.name AS employees_name,
 e1.role AS employees_role,
 d1.name AS department_name
FROM
 `employee_data.employees` AS e1
INNER JOIN
 `employee_data.Department` AS d1
ON
 e1.department_id = d1.department_id;
```